# sortable and new created content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Searching the web I see so many "solutions" of this problem but nothing works for me.

```
<div class='wrap'>
<img class='aimg' src='01.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='aimg' src='02.jpg' alt='img'>
</div>

$(function(){
    $(".wrap").sortable({containment: 'parent'});
});
```

This changes the markup like this:

```
<div class='wrap ui-sortable'>
<img class='aimg ui-sortable-handle' src='01.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='aimg ui-sortable-handle' src='02.jpg' alt='img'>
</div>
```

Everything works, i.e. images are sortable.

Now I add a new content, **identically as above**:

```
var newcontent = "<div class='wrap ui-sortable'>
<img class='aimg ui-sortable-handle' src='01.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='aimg ui-sortable-handle' src='02.jpg' alt='img'>
</div>";

$('newcontent').prependTo($('.container');
```

New content is here but it is not sortable.

Any help?

Comment: @mplungjan did you see that the solution you suggested doesn't work?

Comment: No, I do not. Show me a [mcve] and I will apply one of the many version of the solution - for example what is `$('.container')` ? It is not enough to add something with a class. Sortable does more than just adding a class. It adds event handlers you lost when you replaced the content

Comment: @mplungjan what do you think - what is `container`?

Comment: Instead of answering a question with a question, perhaps update your question with a [mcve] and then we can prove you need to re-initialise sortable when you have new content

Comment: Also this is valid JS `var newcontent = \`<div class='wrap ui-sortable'>
<img class='aimg ui-sortable-handle' src='01.jpg' alt='img'>
<img class='aimg ui-sortable-handle' src='02.jpg' alt='img'>
</div>\`;` when having newlines in the script - the code in your question is not valid unless you do NOT have newlines in the code

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my question.

Comment: You have quote issues. You have `$('newcontent').prependTo` - that will never work here is a working fiddle with prepend BEFORE the sortable https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/zu102gon/

Comment: Since you add a completely new set of stuff, you need to call sortable on that too. If you had JUST added images, you just needed to do `$(".wrap").sortabl("refresh")`  now you need to do `$(".wrap").eq(0).sortable()`  like this https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/su9na312/